# Html5 video fullscreen shutsdown in phonegapp

Tags: html, cordova, html5-video, fullscreen, phonegap

I have a problem with developing an app in phonegapp. I use video tag to play an mp4 file but as soon as I go on fullscreen mode the screen goes off within 30 seconds. 
That happens only in fullscreen mode and doesnt happen at the app itself. The app is running in fullscreen mode also but that is working fine.

I tried [this](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin) plugin but it did not help me fix the problem. I also tried [nosleep.js](https://github.com/richtr/NoSleep.js)
on the webpage where the fullscreen get triggerd but did not help.

This is the html I am using right now

```html
<video id="video" class="video"  width="360" height="240" controls autoplay poster="">\r\n  <source src="http://aljazeera-eng-hd-live.hls.adaptive.level3.net/aljazeera/english2/index1296.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL"><source src="http://telvaza.eu/v1/vid/offlinestream.m3u8" controls autoplay type="application/x-mpegURL">
```

Comment: Video file is in mobile app files or there is some link for video?

Comment: no it is a link. Hls stream video link.